# Problems Installing Impala in Docker

Tags: docker, impala

I tried installing Impala in a docker container following the instructions at:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IMPALA/Impala+Development+Environment+inside+Docker

to the letter. Yet, I got the error below:

```
impdev@eefa956ba515:~/Impala/shell$ sh impala-shell
impala-shell: 32: impala-shell: Bad substitution
ls: cannot access '/home/impdev/Impala/shell/ext-py/*.egg': No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/impdev/Impala/shell/impala_shell.py", line 26, in <module>
    import prettytable
ImportError: No module named prettytable
impdev@eefa956ba515:~/Impala/shell$
```

I need this to assemble my Impala dev environment. Any ideas?
The content of my Dockerfile just says:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
```

After this I run:

```
docker build -t jcabrerazuniga/impalawiki:v1 .
```

To run this container I used (as the manual says):

```
docker run --cap-add SYS_TIME --interactive --tty --name impala-dev-wiki -p 25000:25000 -p 25010:25010 -p 25020:25020 jcabrerazuniga/impalawiki:v1 bash
```

Now, within the container:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install sudo
adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' impdev
echo 'impdev ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
su - impdev
```

Then, as impdev in the container:

```
sudo apt-get --yes install git
git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/impala.git ~/Impala
cd ~/Impala
export IMPALA_HOME=`pwd`
# See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IMPALA/Building+Impala
```

for developing Impala.

```
$IMPALA_HOME/bin/bootstrap_development.sh
```

And while the manual says I can start developing I just saw a terminal prompt. From other terminal I run:

```
docker commit impala-dev-wiki && docker stop impala-dev-wiki
```

and later I run:

```
docker start --interactive impala-dev-wiki
```

and tried to run the impala-shell getting the previous error(s)

Note: It seems the instructions posted at the cwiki page might be outdated. I also tried using Ununtu 14.04 image and I got an error message saying only versions 16.04 and 18.04 are supported. Now I am also trying with 18.04.

Comment: Can you include the actual code you're writing and the actual command you ran?  The error you quote has three errors, with the last one likely caused by one of the two earlier ones; what have you done to debug this?

Comment: Are you actually going into the docker container first, before you try to run the shell? (docker exec -it <container ref no> /bin/bash)